# AWS Lambda Cron Schedule Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, cron, amazon-cloudwatch

I have several Lambda Functions that are on a schedule and those are working without any issues. However, I have a onetime job that I am trying to set up for an existing function and am getting an error when I am creating the new rule:

Details: Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid..

I need this to run on Monday September 26th 2016 at 14:30 hours UTC.

Here are all of the variations I have tried:

- cron(30 14 26 SEP ? 2016)
- cron(30 14 26 9 ? 2016)
- cron(30 14 26 SEP ?*)
- cron(30 14 26 9 ? *)
- cron(30 14 26 SEP MON 2016)
- cron(30 14 26 9 MON 2016)

I must have been staring at this too long because I can't figure out what is the deal on this one. I am using the reference provided here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using web console or CLI? In web console you should not fill the `cron()` part. Your first expression is correct.

See the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, yeah, I figured out what my issue was, your example is what I needed. Thanks!